# How to resolve "Address already in use" exception with TcpListener

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a requirement to use C# for a system that will do the following:

1. Connect to a remote host from a class method Method1
2. Continuously send requests to the remote host in 10 seconds intervals to maintain the connection established in step 1 in another class method Method2
3. In another class method, Method3, listen to the same port from where the requests in steps 1 and 2 were sent

But the problem I have is that when I try step 3, I get the exception

> Address already in use

The following is my code showing the 3 methods

```
public static async Task Method1()
 {
  TcpClient _client = new TcpClient();
  _client = new TcpClient();

  await _client.ConnectAsync("IPAddress", 1234);
  var localEndpoint = (IPEndPoint)_client.Client.LocalEndPoint;
  sourcePort = localEndpoint.Port;
  AppStatics.SourcePort = sourcePort;

  var _stream = _client.GetStream();
  await _stream.WriteAsync("...");
  Task.Run(() => Method2(_stream));
  Method3();
}

public static async Task Method2(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        //Start trying to connect to the remote server here

        Console.WriteLine("Checking the connection with the USSD gateway...");
        var _shakeTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        _shakeTimer.Elapsed += async (object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) => await SendNetworkConnectionCheck(stream);
        _shakeTimer.AutoReset = true;
        _shakeTimer.Enabled = true;

    }

 private static async Task<bool> SendNetworkConnectionCheck(NetworkStream stream)
 {
   stream.Write("...");
 }


  public static void Method3()
  {
   TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, AppStatics.SourcePort);
   listener.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
   listener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        try
        {                
            listener.Stop();
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient acceptTask =  listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                TcpClient incomingClient = acceptTask;

            }
          }
        } catch (SocketException sex)
        {
            if (sex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.AddressAlreadyInUse)
            {
                listener.Stop();
                listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, AppStatics.SourcePort);
                listener.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
                listener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                listener.Start();
            }else
            {                   
                Console.WriteLine(sex.InnerException?.Message ?? sex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was error while trying to listen/handle incoming message");
            string errMsg = ex.InnerException?.Message ?? ex.Message;
            Console.WriteLine(errMsg);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace?.ToString() ?? ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I will appreciate any guidance to get this resolved.
Thank you.

Comment: You can receive data from that original TcpClient instance, there's no need to create a new one.

Comment: @shingo Thank you for your response. Please can you show me more clearly what you mean probably with a sample snippet

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=net-7.0 The examples part contains how to send and receive messages with one TcpClient.

Comment: @shingo I guess you are talking about stream.Read. That is not the area I am having problems. My particular use case as stated requires that another process/method sends a message to that remote server while I listen to requests from the remote server and get the incoming requests - not response to the request I sent but another incoming request from the remote server. The Method 2 keeps sending requests to the server at intervals while I also listen for incoming requests from the server on the same port.

Comment: @shingo I'm actually running on a linux server. I have now updated the question to clearly indicate Method3. Thank you

Comment: The mistake you made is that on client side you should only use a single `TcpClient` instance to send/receive data on the source port. **There is never a need to create another `TcpListener` to listen to the same port, and that's where the exception comes from.**

Comment: @LexLi. Thank you for pointing that out. Could you please create an answer to show that so I can also accept it when I implement it and prove it works. Because I need the code to keep listening for incoming requests from the remote server. If you can show me how to do that without creating the TcpListener, I will really appreciate that. I really look forward to your answer. Thank you

Comment: I am not interested in giving an answer, as how to properly use `TcpClient` probably has been answered hundreds of times in the past two decades. Search engines can take you there, or you just dig further into this class and `NetworkStream`.

Comment: Now I was confused base on the update. When someone says "in another class method", we assume these methods will run **in the same process**". Is it your intent?

Comment: @shingo please see if the last 4 lines of MEthod1 gives a clue to what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Gotcha, but at least TCP is impossible, because it's in-order, rely on a single [sequence number](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc9293.html#name-sequence-numbers), that constrains its ability of communication with multiple sockets.